# CSS @Import usage

Tags: css

How can I use imported CSS in my own CSS ?

If I import : `@import url("animate.css");` to my CSS file, then how can I use it, for example : `.xyz:hover{**fadeIn;)**}`  -fadeIn from **animate.css**?

Comment: If your url path is right; You should be able to write your styles using animate.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is http://daneden.github.io/animate.css, According to the doc, you can add your animation using js with jQuery like:

```
$('.xyz').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).addClass('fadeIn');
});
```